# Unusual Aggression with Other Dogs

Tags: aggression

I have an 8 month old cattle dog who recently has shown aggression towards other dogs at different times. He goes to daycare with groups of dogs, every Friday from 7am to 7pm and does great! He meets new and different dogs every time and never a problem or sign of aggression. However, when I take him on a hike or to the pond and he sees another dog, he gets very aggressive. It used to just be a quick growl and stare, then it escalated to sniffing the other dog and snapping towards its face. We went to Tractor Supply on Sunday and lab walked down another aisle (not near us, but within sight) and as soon as Axle saw him, he showed his teeth, growled and lunged towards the dog. Not in a playful manner. Is he resource guarding me? How can I teach him that other dogs are ok outside of his daycare setting?

Comment: Is he neutered?

Comment: Not a direct answer but just wanted to mention it, because neutering *has* been mentioned: **Do not** consider neutering as an easy way out or guaranteed solution. It might improve things or make them worse. If you're unsure, record the reactions and show them to a professional. Considering the age I could imagine this just being a "teenager" trying to see how far he can go or to prove himself. Maybe it's also associated with some experience, e.g. ending the walk after seeing a dog somewhere specific, etc.